# splunk python api missing fields

Tags: python, splunk

I'm trying to use the python api for splunk following from the search example found here:
http://dev.splunk.com/view/python-sdk/SP-CAAAEE5#normaljob. It's connecting to my application and returning data from a search, but certain fields that are visible when I search using the GUI are not present in the results I get via python.

I seem to be getting some custom fields, but not all of them. Any ideas why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 6 years, but yesterday I had the same issue. I resolved it by appending my search with:

```
| fields <field_1>, <field_2>, ...
```

with `field_x` being a field I want to see in my result.